# OpenLayers 4.5.0: moveend event

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I use moveend event to obtain GeoJson features from server.

```
map.on('moveend', function () {
    reloadVectors({
       'extent': extent,
       'resolution': resolution
    });
});

function reloadVectors(extent, resolution) {...ajax request here...}
```

Too many requests occur while intensive zoom, pan or resize of screen especially. 
Is it possible somehow to defer map movement until the moment when previous data will be drawn?

Answer (score 0):

Stetting async to false does all work

```
$.ajax({    
   url: url,
   type: 'POST',
   async: false,
   dataType: 'json',
   data: data
}).done(function (result) {
...
});
```